# Problems animating heatmap in QGIS temporal controller

Tags: qgis, heat-map, temporal-controller

(QGIS 3.20) I am having trouble getting my heatmap to animate properly using temporal controller. I am using a point layer with many points in the same location so a heatmap would really help visualize the data. But, when using temporal controller, every year shows exactly the same image.
These are the temporal settings I'm using:
[image: Single field with date/time, field=dateconst, event duration = 1 year, accumulate features over time = false]

I have the same layer symbolized as points, with exactly the same temporal settings - this layer animates fine and shows the changes from year to year. So I don't think the problem is with these settings, but I could be wrong.

I generated the heatmap layer by duplicating the point layer and changing the symbology to Heatmap.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Providing more details about your project (settings, data, attributes) or even sharing it could help understanding what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, there were a couple issues going on:

- Null date values were showing up in every frame and needed to be filtered out
- The radius in heatmap symbology was too large, preventing me from seeing the very small changes.
- I played around with the "maximum" option in heatmap symbology to better seperate different densities.